# Three.js PlaneGeometry is giving me on sided texture

Tags: sprite, webgl, three.js

As shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/21/) when rotated, a sprite disapear at some angles, and just one side is rendered. How come? What is the solution to render both sides? Do I have to manipulate the angle?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faces are one-sided by default.

To render both sides, set `mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;`

three.js r.58